# Use default module's action helpers in another module with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, view-helpers

I think I've tried everything I've found to solve this, including all the answers here on SO.

In my project there is an `admin` module, and then there's the default module. Now I want the admin module to use the default module's helpers. Preferably only if there isn't an admin module helper with the same name. Is this possible?

The error message I get is:

> Message: Plugin by name 'HeadBase' was not found in the registry; used
>   paths: Admin_View_Helper_:
>   /application/modules/admin/views\helpers/
>   Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/

I use ZF 1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. In the `Bootstrap`, add an init for helpers, like this:

```
protected function _initHelpers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers/', 'Zend_View_Helper');
}
```

This adds the helper path `APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers/'` for helpers whose class is prefixed with `Zend_View_Helper`.